# A budget audio interface with surface controls and multi-track recording ability

Tags: mixer

I'm currently trying to find an interface which meets my needs for podcast recording. The needs are as follows:

- at least 2 XLR microphone inputs.
- at least 3 line inputs for recording turntables or other line audio.
- the ability to record all tracks separately via USB/Firewire/Thunderbolt onto a Macbook Pro.
- good support for Logic Pro, Audacity or even GarageBand.

Essentially, I want to be able to create a good live mix through an interface with robust controls, but have the option of tweaking levels post-recording on the computer-end through the separately recorded tracks.

Is there anything on the market that would allow this?

I've been looking at the [Zoom R16](http://www.zoom.co.jp/products/r16) but it's unclear as to whether this allows you to record more than the standard one track on the computer-end via the USB.

Finding it hard to distinguish the lexicon used in the specs of these machines to determine if they output more than one track/mix/master etc.

Comment: What does "budget" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although AJ Henderson's answer does clarify things somewhat, I've decided to answer my own question.

Being new to audio production, I think I was confusing the different elements of a production stack. My question was asking for an all-singing, all-dancing interface: something that acted as in i/o, and a controller at the same time.

I realise now that this is a big ask, and that there's nothing wrong with taking a more modular approach. In the end I went with the Focusrite 6i6 and a Korg nanoKontrol.

The Focusrite interface handles my multi-track recording needs, while the Korg ticks the box for a budget control.

Now, all I need to do is make sure my software is set-up accordingly - something I have outlined in [this queston](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/how-can-i-automate-track-levels-while-recording-in-logic-mainstage-garageband).

Answer (score 0):

From your link. "The R16 functions as an audio interface enabling direct input of sound to a computer. Support for high quality 24-bit/96kHz encoding ensures great sound. Eight input channels and two output channels can be used simultaneously."  Presonus also makes similar products.

Comment: This is helpful, but I think I needed a nudge in the direction of accepting a more modular approach. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Shennan - cool, glad you figured out more about what you were looking for.  Thanks for posting it as an answer too.  I +1'd your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you might be able to answer my other question? It has a juicy bounty...